# how to get excerpt from solr in solarium

Tags: apache, solr, solarium

How can I use Highlighening text and getting the excerpt( the sentences along with matched words  ) using solr , and i am suing solarium  ? can it be done using solarium,  i dont have any idea about this , kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Solr support highlighting out of the box.
You would need to enable the [highlighting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) feature and mark the fields accordingly to enable the highlighting.

Solarium is a Solr client and provides apis to retrieve the highlight information. check [example](http://wiki.solarium-project.org/index.php/V2%3aHighlighting_result).

Comment: Hey , thanks  . . I have done with Highlightening , i did it in my PHP code , But I am not able to get the excerpt of the content